# What is the preferred method of getting variable values in an ItemizedOverlay's draw method?

Tags: java, android

Using an ArrayList of GeoPoints, I'm looking to draw points on a map and connect them with a line.  I've got the "point" part working, but not the lines.  My ItemizedOverlay class:

```
private class myItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
{
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private ArrayList<GeoPoint> geoPoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    private int color;

    public myItemizedOverlay (Drawable marker, ArrayList<GeoPoint> gp, int c)
    {
        super(marker);
        geoPoints = gp;
        color = c;

        boundCenter(marker);

        for (int i = 0; i < geoPoints.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            items.add(new OverlayItem(geoPoints.get(i)));
        }

        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i)
    {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        Point p1 = new Point();
        Point p2 = new Point();

        for (int i = 1; i < geoPoints.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPoints.get(i), p1);
            int x1 = p1.x;
            int y1 = p1.y;

            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPoints.get(i - 1), p2);
            int x2 = p2.x;
            int y2 = p2.y;

            canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

called with:

```
myItemizedOverlay mo = new myItemizedOverlay(marker, geoPoints, color);
mapView.getOverlays().add(mo);
```

I'm finding that "geoPoints" is empty in the overridden "draw" method, and I can't figure out why.  Even more confusing is that "color" is /not/ empty, and both "color" and "geoPoints" are assigned the same way.  Can anybody recommend a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning `gp` to `geoPoints`. I expect somewhere else you are clearing `gp`. You should be doing a copy:

```
geoPoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>(geoPoints.size());
for (int i = 0; i < geoPoints.size() - 1; i++)
        {
            geoPoints.add(gp.get(i));
            items.add(new OverlayItem(geoPoints.get(i)));
        }
```

Try that and let me know how that works.